# Como criar uma nova instância ao invés de apontar para a mesma instância ao definir variável?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, php-7, instanciar-objeto

Ao definir uma variável do tipo [`Carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) eu não consigo copiar o objeto (criar nova instância com as mesmas propriedades), apenas apontar para a mesma instância, me obrigando a criar novos objetos manualmente.

Exemplo:

```
$data_inicio  = Carbon::now()
                     ->hour(0)
                     ->minute(0)
                     ->second(0);

\var_dump($data_inicio); // retorna data 2019-07-19

$data_limite = $data_inicio;
$data_limite->addWeeks(8);
\var_dump($data_inicio); // retorna data 2019-09-13
\var_dump($data_limite); // retorna data 2019-09-13
```

Há uma forma de copiar a instância ao invés de apontar para a mesma instância do objeto, de forma que ao alterar a variável `$data_limite` eu não altere `$data_inicio`?

Comment: Tal como `$data_limite = clone $data_inicio`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a palavra reservada [clone](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.cloning.php).

```
$data_limite = clone $data_inicio;
```

Como o *@AndersonCarlosWoss* disse:

> O clone fará a clonagem rasa, isso é, as referências internas se
>   manterão intactas. Se a instância original depende de outra instância,
>   esta segunda será compartilhada com a instância clonada, exceto se
>   explicitamente a classe preveja isso na implementação do método
>   __clone.

A documentação do PHP também menciona isso:

> [..] se seu objeto guarda uma **referência a outro objeto** que usa e ao replicar o objeto pai, deseja-se que seja criada uma **nova instância desse outro objeto** para que a réplica tenha sua própria cópia separada. [...]

Comment: O `clone` fará a clonagem rasa, isso é, as referências internas se manterão intactas. Se a instância original depende de outra instância, esta segunda será compartilhada com a instância clonada, exceto se explicitamente a classe preveja isso na implementação do método `__clone`. Não sei se entendi certo, mas me pareceu que você quis dizer na resposta que mesmo as instâncias internas serão clonadas.

Comment: Na verdade eu tentei explicar o que você explicou claramente. Preciso melhorar minhas respostas e obrigado por alertar :)